# Entity Framework creates a database with a wrong name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two projects in my solution:

- An ASP.NET Web API project with EF
- A console app with EF

Both projects are configured to connect to SQL Server and have the same connection string defined in the `app/web.config`:

```
<add name="AppContext" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=XYZAC;Integrated Security=True" />
```

The problem only occurs with the console app. The web app creates the `XYZAC` database correctly. The console app, however, creates a database with the name along the lines of `Namespace.AppContext`, which isn't at all what I need. Because of that there is no communication between these projects.

I tried changing `Database=` to `Initial Catalog=` in the connection string of the console app, but it didn't change anything.

What can be the cause of this? Can this be happening because the API is logging in via `IIS APPPOOL\XYZAC` user and the app via `WINSRV\Administrator`? Seems unlikely, because both have pretty much the same permission groups and access to everything, but I'm not sure what else can be the cause.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**: I'm sharing the DB models between these two projects. I'll try hard-coding the connection string into the constructor.

Comment: Check your `DbContext` constructor.  I'm guessing you aren't telling it to use the .config's connection string.

Comment: Also console app doesn't use web.config. It uses your.app.name.exe.cofig file.

Comment: You need add `app.config` for your console application.

Comment: Simple answer is don't use EF... Use Dapper!

Comment: I'm sharing the same DB models between these two projects, the connectionStrings have the same name so it should work in both if one does... right? I guess I didn't explain that part in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard-coding the same string like this solved the problem:

```
public AppContext() : base("Sql n stuff;XYZAC")
```

Cool. As long as it works, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try scaffolding from created xyz database to the console application and see if it connects with the scaffolded context  .